# How can I monitor Heroku multi-dynos app with Prometheus?

Tags: heroku, monitoring, prometheus

I need monitor apps deployed to Heroku by Prometheus monitoring system.

Problem is that if you have more dynos app, you need to know all IP address of your dynost to be able to pull metrics from all dynos.

For K8s or AWS we are able to get full list of PODs/instances, So you are able to do this.

So question is, do you know, how to get IPs of all dynos from Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

I'm considering exposing [the $DYNO environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#local-environment-variables) as a label to all metrics so Prometheus can have a consistent view on which dyno it's scraping. Given a short enough scraping interval, all dynos should be able to scraped within reasonable time.

Pushgateway is not a recommended way of monitoring long-standing services.

Answer (score 1):

> So question is, do you know, how to get IPs of all dynos from Heroku?

This is not possible on the Heroku platform. The application dynos sit behind a load balancer, you do not have direct access to them.

> I need monitor apps deployed to Heroku by Prometheus monitoring system.

Perhaps this could be split into two Prometheus jobs.

1. Monitor the application directly (at it's load-balanced `*.herokuapp.com/metrics` endpoint)
2. and use an exporter that gathers the dynos metrics via push somehow

Consider making use of a Heroku log drain to an exporter, converting the logs into a metrics endpoint.

There is also a private API available on Heroku application stats, not the best idea, but it might work well to gather the basic application stats. Have a look at the network requests in the Heroku dashboard to see how that works.

This would have some similarities with using a pushgateway, as described at https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/.